# with JQUERY, How to pass a dynamic series of data to the server

Tags: jquery

What is the recommended way in JQUERY to send a dynamic set of data to the server, the set contains items like:

ID: 13
Copy:

hello world....hello world....hello world....hello world....

ID: 122
Copy:

Ding dong ...Ding dong ...**Ding dong** ...Ding dong ...Ding dong ...

ID: 11233
Copy:

mre moremore ajkdkjdksjkjdskjdskjdskjds

This could range from 1, to 10 items. What's the best way to structure that data to post to the server with JQUERY?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON array.  Note that this is the string representation of a JavaScript array.

```
'[
   {"ID": 13,
   "Copy": "hello world....hello world....hello world....hello world...."},
   {"ID": 122,
   "Copy": "Ding dong ...Ding dong ...Ding dong ...Ding dong ...Ding dong ..."},
   {"ID": 11233,
    "Copy": "mre moremore ajkdkjdksjkjdskjdskjdskjds"}
 ]'
```

You can create this programatically  using something like::

```
var array = [];
for(...)
{
  var newEl = {};
  newEl.ID = ...
  newEl.Copy = ...
  array.push(newEl);
}

var jsonText = JSON.stringify(array);
```

You then pass jsonText as the data parameter to $.ajax.

Comment: Suggestions for how to create a JSON array?

Comment: SLaks don't you have to serialize it to send it through GET or POST? I usually do...

Comment: @SLaks, @Alex, yes, it needs to be stringified, and jQuery does not handle this for you.

Comment: @Alex: No, it doesn't need to be stringified. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ `Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key i.e. {foo:["bar1", "bar2"]} becomes '&foo=bar1&foo=bar2'.`

Comment: @SLaks, no.  I got misled by those same docs before.  It does have to be.  It won't encode an object to JSON, even if you specify application/json as the request content type.  See this [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EnPHC/3/).

Comment: From the source: `// convert data if not already a string
  if ( s.data && s.processData && typeof s.data !== "string" ) {
   s.data = jQuery.param( s.data, s.traditional );
  }`

Comment: @SLaks, jQuery.param converts to a type of URL-encoded string, *not* JSON. Take a look at the demo.  It serializes the array to the junk value "undefined=undefined".